# plotshape - text colour displayed incorrectly with user defined input variables

Tags: colors, pine-script

There seems to be a bug in the compiler of Pine Script, in this below example the use of a variable called `transp` sets a user definable input value for the transparency of a given colour.

Yet when using `plotshape` and `bgcolor` it has inconsistent results. `bgcolour` works as expected, `plotshape` however behaves very oddly. It sets the colour correctly for the plotted shape using `style=shape.cross`, but it fails to understand the colour instruction for the `text = ‘hi’` or `text = ‘lo’`. In this case it uses the default colour of blue.

If you change `transp` to a set integer like `transp = 80`, it then works correctly and displays both the shape and text in the given colour. This is incredibly bogus, if it merely didn’t accept variables assigned to user inputs for transparency then it would affect both shape and text. You could also just enter the `color.new` expression straight into `plotshape`, and this works in the same way, use a variable for transparency that has a user input associated to it and it will not work correctly, use a hardcoded integer assignment and it works fine.

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='RSI and test colour variable', shorttitle='Colour test', overlay=false)

transp = input.int(60, minval=0, maxval=100, title='Transparency:')

blue  = color.new(color.blue, 0)
green = color.new(color.green, transp)
red   = color.new(color.red, transp)
white = color.new(color.white, 0)

lower = 30
higher = 60
Len = input(title='RSI Length:', defval=10)
Src = input(title='RSI Source:', defval=close)
rsi = ta.rsi(Src, Len)
plot(rsi, color=white)

plot(lower, color=blue)
plot(higher, color=blue)

plotshape (rsi > higher, location=location.top, color=green, style=shape.cross, text='Hi', size=size.tiny)
bgcolor (rsi > higher  ? green : na)
 
plotshape (rsi < lower, location=location.top, color=red, style=shape.cross, text='Lo', size=size.tiny)
bgcolor (rsi < lower  ? red : na)
```

I have looked over this and tried every conceivable permutation to the code to get around this, and it always responds in the same incoherent manner. It took sometime to actually realise what the issue was, this is clearly a bug, not overly fatal, but it’s not an ideal presentation, and I can’t move on with this bug looking at me, still bugging me.  ;o\

Any work-arounds?

Comment: Thx for the report. Although @vitruvius's workaround will solve your problem, it does look like unexpected behavior. We have logged a report to the Pine team.

Comment: OK, very good, does that entitle me to a refund/discount/credit on my TV PRO+ subscription that I just renewed for another year? ;)

Comment: Sorry but no. We do appreciate the report. There's a [bounty program](https://www.tradingview.com/bounty/) for security-related bug reports, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might not be the reason, it does not necessarily need to be a user defined input. The value needs to be known at compile time.

If you try `transp=close > 2 ? 40 : 80`, you will get the same behavior.

[Some more info.](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Colors.html)

As a workaround, use the `textcolor` parameter.

```
plotshape (rsi > higher, location=location.top, color=green, textcolor=green, style=shape.cross, text='Hi', size=size.tiny)
plotshape (rsi < lower, location=location.top, color=red, textcolor=red, style=shape.cross, text='Lo', size=size.tiny)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. I would up vote you but I haven't enough reputation for such matters, even on my own question!